# IntelliJ: how did I manage to get a v (check) sign next to the line numbers?

Tags: intellij-idea

For some reason I managed to get a v sign (like a check sign) next to my line numbers in IntelliJ and I have no idea how it got there. It also marks as a dark blue/black error mark on the right side.

Not only do I wanna know how to remove it because it annoys the hell out of me, but I wanna know how to turn it on again too! ;) Could come in handy some other time :)

Comment: Edit: I managed to turn it of by pressing ctrl + shift + 1 and then angain to remove the 1 sign it got replaced by, but I still don't know how to turn it back on or what it does..

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`Edit` | `Toggle Bookmark` (<kbd>F11</kbd>).

**Edit:** (2017/08/23)

In IntelliJ 2017 it is under `Navigate` | `Bookmarks` | `Toggle Bookmark` (<kbd>F3</kbd>)

Comment: Happens far too easily while hitting backspace on my keyboard, resulted in quite some confusion :)

Comment: In WebStorm 2016 (and, presumably, other newer versions of JetBrains IDEs), it's Navigate | Bookmarks | Toggle Bookmark (or Navigate | Bookmarks | Show Bookmarks to view all of them).